# Android: Displaying many images , OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, image, out-of-memory

I have an app where I want to display images like in the BBC app.

[image]

But I don't load them from a server, all pictures are in the res folder.
There are at least 72 images (jpg), all ~512*340 (each ~10kB).  All together have about 1MB.

I want to display them in 340*225 and only show their full size if you click on them.

I tried to implement this via XML and via Java alone, but i only get an outofmemory when there are displayed more than 12 images.

I have searched for a solution for hours now and still havent found any.
I read the android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html 
and many other stackoverflow questions, but they don't look suitable for my problem.

How do i load the images into my activity? How can I resize them without wasting much RAM?

**edit:**

Now I load all images in my onCreate() :

```
ImageView ivDOK01 = new ImageView(this);
ivDOK01.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.vo_dok01, 240, 164));

ivDOK01.setOnClickListener(this);
ivDOK01.setMaxWidth(240);
ivDOK01.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
ivDOK01.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

--> 72 times

The setImageBitmap is from the android developer tutorial.

**EDIT 2:**
With this method I can display 30 of the 72 images before I get the outofmemoryerror.

But I would have a problem if images were a little bit bigger.

Is there an option to only have the images in the RAM that are displayed?
How does the normal Android Galery do that, where you can scoll fast over hundreds of images?

Comment: user2982446 use lazy loadi9ng to fix problem.

Comment: Try to use volley to show images or load image into Gallery.

Comment: Are u trying yo load all 72 images on the page loading? If yes then you have to use some reusable component such as GridView to load the images

Comment: How can lazy loading or GridView solve the OutOfMemoryError ?  Its still 72 images with 340*225 in one layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution:**

I converted the jpg Images to bmp (where they were about 12mb) and reduced the qualtity and the size to 340*225. (Now they have about 4mb)

Then I just load them asynchron into the program.

Next I will try how I can use jpg without loosing performace or getting too much memory.

Comment: Bare in mind that the size of the image in disk does not influence how much the image will take in memory. What matters is the resolution. For instance, assuming a bitmap of ARGB_8888, which it most certainly is, your images will take 512 * 340 * 4 bytes fof memory which is 0.7MB. That, times 72, will get you 50MB of memory which is of course too much for a single app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many library class to avoid memory issue most of them using the lazy image loading, [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is a good one

Comment: I used this library but it seems to be very slow...  And additionally its unecessary complicated. I mean, I just want to display some images. There are so many apps which do exactly the same, there must be an easy way to accomplish this.